# Blank Space / Whitespace Character for .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

this rule is working for me but i have a problem
www.domain.com/description_functionhall/117/A%2520S%2520Garden
second rule is taking %2520 so i want that url in this format
www.domain.com/description_functionhall/117/A-S-Garden

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /function_hall_project/

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?hall_id=([^&\s]+)&booking_date=([^&\s]+)&session=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3/%4? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?hall_id=$2&booking_date=$3&session=$4 [L,QSA]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?hall_id=123&name=abcd to /dir/foo/123/abcd
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?hall_id=([^&\s]+)&name=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?hall_id=$2&name=$3 [L,QSA]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?id=123 to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?hall_id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/? [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?id=12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?hall_id=$2 [L,QSA]



# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert this rule just below `## hide .php extension snippet` line to convert all these white spaces to hyhen:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%2520|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks. its working and one more thing can i make my url like this www.domain.com/description_functionhall/A-S-Garden in simple way can i hide that id 117 from url using .htaccess, if possible pls send me that rule.@anubhava

Comment: Actually that won't be possible since without `hall_id` your php code won't work. Also for asking new question please create a new question.